# Android app with many pages of context with Titanium studio classic

Tags: android, titanium

I am quite new with developing with Titanium studio and so I would like to ask for some pointers in developing one of my first Android application. I am having problems in organizing myselft through windows and wievs. The problem is that the application will have much textual context on different pages, navigating will be done with slider menu and swiping left or right. So I would like to ask what is the correct approach of doing this. Also application will have same background on all pages and slider menu will be on all pages. Is there possibility to have one window with the background set and slider menu, and all others would be included views? Please point me in the right direction. I am working with classic titanium.
BR
Edi

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to navigate to right or left by swiping, you can use [Ti.UI.ScrollableView](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.ScrollableView).
While using a scrollableView, you just need to create a single window and a ScrollableView. Create other pages as views. Please check the following code

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow();

var view1 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#123' });
var view2 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#246' });
var view3 = Ti.UI.createView({ backgroundColor:'#48b' });
var myPages = [view1,view2,view3]; //Array containing the views
var scrollableView = Ti.UI.createScrollableView({
  views: myPages,
  showPagingControl:true
});

win.add(scrollableView);
win.open();
```